# .done is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've another problem. I get an error in FireFox and I don't know what my fault is. I always did it like this way and I never got an error. I already check lower/uppercase mistakes but I can't find anything.

Thanks

> $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "ajax/check_username.php", data: {username: username}}).done is not a function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#username").keyup(function(){
        var username = $("#username").val();
        $(".usernameFeedback").fadeIn("fast");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/check_username.php",
            data: { username: username }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            $("#loadingImage").hide();
            if(msg.status != "error")
                {
                    if(msg.available == "yes")
                    {
                        $(".usernameFeedback span").text(msg.message);
                        $(".usernameFeedback span").removeClass("notok");
                        $(".usernameFeedback span").addClass("ok");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(".usernameFeedback span").text(msg.message);
                        $(".usernameFeedback span").addClass("notok");
                    }
                }
        });
        return(false);
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: What does the ajax function return if not a Deferred? Try to log that to the console.

Answer (score 17):

Probably your jQuery version is too old. You need at least jQuery 1.5 for jqXHR objects to implement the *Promise* interface you are using.

If you cannot upgrade for some reason, simply use the `success` option:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/check_username.php",
    data: { username: username },
    success: function(msg) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was using an old version (1.4.2). I replaced it by (1.7.2). I got no errors anymore but i have still a coding fault. The application must check if a username is available(at runtime) but the output is always not available, but i will look for my fault. THanks!

Comment: The alternate solution worked for me. Thanks and +1.